# Same color for data on both primary and secondary y-axis

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which plots test results for a specific batch. My test results give two data sets which are numerically very different so I need to plot it into a primary and secondary y-axis.

My problem is that I would like for the coloring to be the same for the same lot.

The below code works for plotting the data, but I would like to combine them so the name is mentioned once and the color is the same.

Is that possible?

Best Regards
Lonnie

```
With ActiveChart
I = 1
    Do Until I = TestNr + 1
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(I + 4).Name = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & 11 + I)
        .SeriesCollection(I + 4).XValues = Sheets("Data").Range("B4:P4")
        .SeriesCollection(I + 4).Values = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & 11 + I & ":P" & 11 + I)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(I + 4).Select
With Selection
    .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Border.Weight = xlThin
End With
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(I + 4).AxisGroup = 1
        I = I + 1
    Loop
End With

With ActiveChart
J = 1
    Do Until J = TestNr + 1
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(J + 4 + TestNr).Name = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & 11 + J)
        .SeriesCollection(J + 4 + TestNr).XValues = Sheets("Data").Range("B4:P4")
        .SeriesCollection(J + 4 + TestNr).Values = Sheets("Data").Range("R" & 11 + J & ":AF" & 11 + J)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(J + 4 + TestNr).Select
With Selection
    .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Border.Weight = xlThin
End With
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(J + 4 + TestNr).AxisGroup = 2
        J = J + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for the above issue, and figured I would post it in case someone else had the same issue. Might not be the prettiest solution, but it works ok.

```
Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte
Dim K As Variant
With ActiveChart
K = 1
    Do Until K = TestNr + 1
    r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
    g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
    b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4 + K).Select
        With Selection
                .Border.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
                .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(r, g, b)
                .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(r, g, b)
        End With
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4 + K + TestNr).Select
        With Selection
                .Border.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
                .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(r, g, b)
                .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(r, g, b)
        End With
    K = K + 1
    Loop
End With
```